# DB2 Query Error SQL0204N Even With The Schema Defined

Tags: python, db2, pyodbc

I'm using pyodbc to access DB2 10.1.0

I have a login account named foobar and a schema with the same name. I have a table named users under the schema.

When I'm logged in as foobar, I can run the following query successfully from the command line:

```
select * from users
```

I have a small Python script that I'm using to connect to the database.  The script is:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import pyodbc

if  __name__ == "__main__":

    accessString ="DRIVER={DB2};DATABASE=MYDATABASE;SERVER=localhost;UID=foobar; PWD=foobarish1;CURRENTSCHEMA=FOOBAR" 
    print accessString
    cnxn = pyodbc.connect(accessString , autocommit=True)
    cursor = cnxn.cursor()
    query = "SELECT * FROM USERS"
    cursor.execute(query)
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    for row in rows:
        print 'Row data'
        print row[0]
    cursor.close()
    cnxn.close()
```

When I run the script, I get the following error:

('42S02', '[42S02] [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/LINUXX8664] SQL0204N  "FOOBAR.USERS" is an undefined name.  SQLSTATE=42704\n (-204) (SQLExecDirectW)')

This usually means that the schema isn't defined.  However, if I change the query in the script to:

```
VALUES CURRENT SCHEMA
```

the script runs successfully and it returns

```
FOOBAR
```

Does anyone know how to fix this so I can query the user table?  Your assistance and insight is appreciated.

EDIT: I've also tried adding the schema directly to the table name, making the query

```
SELECT * FROM FOOBAR.USERS
```

and I still get the same error.

Comment: What does this show when run from the command line: `"select tabschema, tabname from syscat.tables where upper(tabname) = 'USERS'"`? And what happens if you **don't** use the `CURRENTSCHEMA` property in `accessString`?

Comment: @mustaccio Thanks for the response. When I run the query, I get FOOBAR and USERS. When I remove CURRENTSCHEMA, I still have the same results listed in the OP.

Comment: The only other explanation I can offer is that you are connecting to two different databases.

Comment: Why didn't you provide a connection-port to your database? Perhaps it differs from default?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and solved it by setting the SCHEMA explicit by query:

```
 SET CURRENT SCHEMA foobar
```